# Finding distance between two co-ordinates python

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array, geometry

I have a function which takes 3 x and y co-ordinates
1st one is center of circle, 2nd is co-ordinate on left circumference of circle on same line
and 3rd co-ordinate is perpendicular to the centre on top circumference.
I am trying to create a box to cover the circle and then iterate through each co-ordinate to see if it is inside the circle. 
for some reason the for range is behaving abnormally for me

```
def addall(cx,cy, lx,ly,tx,ty): 
    sx = lx
    sy = ty- 2*(abs(cy-ty))
    fx = sx+ 2*(abs(lx-cx))
    fy = ty     

    for i in range (sy, fy+1):
        for j in range(sx,fx+1):
            if(((cx-lx)**2 + (cy-ly)**2 ) >= ((cx-j)**2+(cy-i)**2)):                                                    
                print( i)
                print(j)
                print((cx-lx)**2 + (cy-ly)**2 )
                print((cx-i)**2+(cy-j)**2)
                print("------")


addall(4,4 ,2,4,4,6)
```

The print out is weird. both i and j are changing randomly

```
2
4
4
4
------
3
3
4
2
------
3
4
4
1
------
3
5
4
2
------
4
2
4
4
------
4
3
4
1
------
4
4
4
0
------
etc
```

Comment: Your `print(i)` and `print(j)` are within an if statement. You print `i` and `j` only when the condition to enter the `if` is `True`. Maybe that's the reason, you might want to check that.

Comment: Also, a better explanation of the points location might help or even an image could ease the task of understanding what you are trying to accomplish with your code.

Comment: Yeah it was my fault. So every co-ordinate has a value and i have to add everything in the circle. Trying to measure brightness of a star.Thankss